# "$state.current.data.parameter" does not update when hitting substate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**Updated:**
Of cause I missed to add what controller it was, it does change the value of the property but it does not show/hide my divs when I click the route trigger. The current html setup does show/hide on first load. What would I be missing here?

I need help with understanding and finding a solution to my issue. I'm using ui-router and got two routes, one main and one substate.

```
$stateProvider.state('analyse', {
        url: '/analyse/:id',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/some/some.html',
        controller: 'Analyse',
        data: {
            customData1: false
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('analyse.solution', {
        url: '/solution',
        views: {
            'ui-solution': {
                template: 'testing the template',
                data: {
                    customData1: true
                }
            }   
        },
        controller: 'Analyse'
    });
```

in my controller it updates this value

```
vm.selectSolution = $state.current.data.customData1;
```

Now hitting the main router `analyse` it does update the `vm.selectedSolution`, but hitting the substate it does nothing, the value does not change. I'm hiding/showing two divs depending on that value.

**EDIT**: My html looks like

```
<div ng-controller="Analyse as vmSolution" ui-view="ui-solution" ng-show="vmSolution.selectSolution"></div>

<div ng-controller="Analyse as vmSolution" class="analysis-solution" ng-hide="vmSolution.selectSolution">
```

Why, and what can I do that will change the value on the substate?

Comment: can you please show us, your html code? how are you handling that part?

Comment: Try putting the `data` of `analyse.solution` outside the `views` settings

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval Updated question. I can confirm that part works.

Comment: @AlonEitan makes no difference

Comment: you can see the state.name when you're debugging? how are you controlling the state change?

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval It does write to the console and the url change. The main state is in my navigation, the substate trigger is in my main `ui-view`, my `ui-solution` `ui-view` is in the main view

Comment: @Dejan.S Can you try using `params`  instead of `data`, and then inject `$stateParams` into the controller - And get the data like this: `vm.selectSolution = $stateParams.customData1;` ?

Comment: the `controller` to the ui-router is the solution.